# Removing parts of a multidimensional array that do not have a key that matches a separate array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array that is full of IDs that will match corresponding IDs in a separate array which is larger in terms of indices. I would like to first search through the larger array using the IDs from the smaller array and eliminate any indices that do not appear in the smaller array, and then place values present in the arrays that do match in my initial, smaller array. I have tried various nested for loops (come close, but does not get me there) but I can't seem to wrap my head about some array problems in general.

First array will look something like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [roleID] => 5b6468a500277c71b98405b1f140991c
        [name] => 
        [description] => 
        [rate] => 
        [hours] => 
        [total] => 
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [roleID] => 5b6468a500277c74f6b2c065436b7d17
        [name] => 
        [description] => 
        [rate] => 
        [hours] => 
        [total] => 
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [roleID] => 5b6468a500277c7697ba21928129e3af
        [name] => 
        [description] => 
        [rate] => 
        [hours] => 
        [total] => 
    )
```

)

Second array will look something like this

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [ID] => 5b6468a500277c71b98405b1f140991c
        [name] => CED
        [objCode] => ROLE
        [description] => CED
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [ID] => 5b6468a500277c74f6b2c065436b7d17
        [name] => AD
        [objCode] => ROLE
        [description] => AD
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [ID] => 5b6468a500277c7697ba21928129e3af
        [name] => AMG
        [objCode] => ROLE
        [description] => AMG
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [ID] => 5b6468a500277c77071c32c0bb2bae04
        [name] => AP
        [objCode] => ROLE
        [description] => AP
    )

[4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [ID] => 5b6468a500277c787e9680625c74ca80
        [name] => AST
        [objCode] => ROLE
        [description] => AST
    )

[5] => stdClass Object
    (
        [ID] => 5b6468a500277c79c0eddb8c14cc9f83
        [name] => ASV
        [objCode] => ROLE
        [description] => ASV
    )
```

)

I want to match the roleID in the first ID with the ID in the second array, then take the 'name' and 'description' keys and put it in the first array in the position it belongs. I have gotten close with the below code, but either a bunch of the arrays get misordered, or the 'name' and 'description' fields are the exact same for every index.

```
    $projectUserRoleIDs = $client->get('project', $myProjectName, array('projectUserRoles:roleID'));
    $projectUserRoleIDs = $projectUserRoleIDs->projectUserRoles;

    $roleIDs = [];

    for($a = 0; $a < count($projectUserRoleIDs); $a++)
    {
        $roleIDs[$a]['roleID'] = $projectUserRoleIDs[$a]->roleID;


            // Get array of entire list of roles that are available in Workfront
            // The roles:name category has all of the acronyms for each role, which can appear in an invoice
            // The roles:description category has all of the full length names

            $projectRoles = $client->get('project', $myProjectName, array('roles:name', 'roles:description'));
            $projectRoles = $projectRoles->roles;

            $roleLoop = [];
            for($b = 0; $b < count($projectUserRoleIDs); $b++)
            {
                $roleLoop[] = $projectUserRoleIDs[$b]->roleID;
            }

            foreach($roleLoop as $key => $value) {
                for($x = 0; $x<count($projectRoles); $x++)
                {
                    if($projectRoles[$x]->ID === $value)
                    {
                        $name = $projectRoles[$x]->name;
                        $description = $projectRoles[$x]->description;

                        $roleIDs[$x]['name'] = $name;
                        $roleIDs[$x]['description'] = $description;
                    }
                }
            }







        $roleIDs[$a]['rate'] = '';
        $roleIDs[$a]['hours'] = '';
        $roleIDs[$a]['total'] = '';
    }
```

In the end I want my first array to look like this

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [roleID] => 5b6468a500277c71b98405b1f140991c
        [name] => CED
        [description] => CED
        [rate] => 
        [hours] => 
        [total] => 
    )
[1] => Array
(
    [roleID] => 5b6468a500277c74f6b2c065436b7d17
    [name] => AD
    [description] => AD
    [rate] => 
    [hours] => 
    [total] => 
)
```

And so on... any help is appreciated and thank you.

Comment: If you can post `var_export` of the arrays I can test it.

Comment: Someone did you no favors leaving these Arrays associative-indexed. Do you have control over what these data structures look like?

Comment: I think i can alter the data structures, they are returned as objects but i stripped out the excess